# The Ok button of MessageBox closes the form

Tags: vb.net

I have a main form **formA** and empty form **formB**, formA opens formB, on the load event of formB it add a user control using `Activator.CreateInstance(ControlType)` .. the user control has Submit and Cancel buttons. 
this is the btnOk.click event

```
Private Sub btnOk_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOk.Click
    Try
        If OnSubmit() = cSUCCESS Then

            OnSubmitRaiseEvent(e)

        Else
        '
        ' what should I write here to Not close the form if onSubmit failed ?
        '
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        WriteToEventLog(ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```

the `OnSubmit()` method checks for some data if valid or not, if not, it shows a message Box with OK button. The problem is that OK button on the message box closes the formB that is hosting the user control.

I want Message box to close and user can resume working on the form

How can I solve this?

Comment: If you want us to be able to identify any issues you would of course have to show us the troubling code. In other words: the `OnSubmit()` method's code.

Comment: @VisualVincent I described it in words, it does nothing but checking the input and show a messagebox with Ok button

Comment: It is still good to show us the code so we can be sure if it... Anyway, if you are certain that nothing in there is the cause then it's fine by me. -- Have you made sure that it isn't `OnSubmitRaiseEvent()` or any of its supposed event handlers that close the form? What happens if you remove that line?